# SwiftUI Canvas Drawing Text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw labels above lines using a Canvas in SwiftUI. The lines draw at the correction position, however the labels are never drawn above the lines (see screenshot which shows both the "1" and "2" label drawn atop each other).

[image]

I use a for loop to get the position data from an array:

```
Canvas {context, size in
            let font = Font.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 16)
            
            
            for line in TLDataModel.lines {
                let resolved = context.resolve(Text(line.tickLabel).font(font))
                let midPoint = CGPoint(x: line.points.startIndex, y: line.points.endIndex)
                context.draw(resolved, at: midPoint, anchor: .center)
                print("Line Label: \(line.tickLabel)")
                print("..for points: \(line.points)")
                var path = Path()
                path.addLines(line.points)
                context.stroke(path, with: .color(.blue), lineWidth: 1.0)
            }
            
        }.frame(width: (400), height: 100, alignment: .leading)
```

And my class:

```
class testDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lines: [line] = []
    
    init(){
        var nl = line(points: [CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 100.0)], tickLabel: "1")
        addLines(newLine: nl)
        nl = line(points: [CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100.0)], tickLabel: "2")
        addLines(newLine: nl)
    }
    
    func addLines (newLine: line){
        lines.append(newLine)
    }
}

public struct line: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    
    let points: [CGPoint]
    let tickLabel: String
}
```

Comment: You're using `line.points.startIndex` and `line.points.startIndex` to get the `midPoint` of your line -- the indexes have nothing to do with the actual midpoint -- it'll always return `0` and `2` for arrays with two elements. You need to calculate the actual x,y location. Also, consider using the Swift standard practices of capitalizing type names and using lowercase letters to start property names.

Comment: @jnpdx - how to mark as answered and associate to you?

Comment: You can add the answer yourself if you want.